# what is the difference between robolectric and androidx.test?

Tags: junit, junit4, robolectric, android-jetpack, androidx

Can some one explain me How it makes difference when i use robolectric seperately with gradle along with androidx.test and just use androix.test without roboelectric.

I have found some article which is saying that , latest version of robolectric support androidx.test , but not much examples about this , so i am little confused about how really this combination will work and helpful in writing unit test.

Any help regarding this query is appreciated.